# PHP generated CSS not taking effect

Tags: php, css, wordpress, chmod

## What I have:

A `style-color.php` document that dynamically writes/outputs CSS code that should ordinarily be applied to my website's pages (note: this is a theme file for a WordPress based website).

## My problem:

The file works perfectly locally however does not on my live website. By process of elimination, the only real difference that come to mind between my local and live environments are security hardening measures I've applied to the live environment and potentially chmod settings.

**Security hardening:** 
I've disabled various security hardening measures but to no avail.

[image: Screenshot]

**chmod settings:**
The `style-colors.php` is contained in `themes > some-theme-name > style-colors.php` and the respective permissions are `755 > 755 > 644`.

## My question:

Is there anything obvious I'm overlooking with regards to the permissions or anything else that might be preventing `style-colors.php` from behaving as it should?

Comment: Hard to help you if you don't post some code!

Comment: are you sending css/text headers `header(“Content-type: text/css”);` from your php? Maybe?

Comment: How are you loading the `style-colors.php` file? Is it being included to the page via php inside a `<style>` tag? Or is it linked externally via a `<link>` tag? Have you tried clearing your cache (browser and if you have any sort of wordpress caching)?

Comment: @DaveGoten Yes, that's correct. `header( 'Content-type: text/css;' ); url  = dirname( __FILE__ ); $strpos = strpos( $url, 'wp-content' ); $base = substr( $url, 0, $strpos ); require_once( $base .'wp-load.php' );`

Comment: Sometimes wordpress (and other frameworks) may also cache some things such as stylesheets, is there a cache somewhere that you can empty manually? Is it your browser cache, did that cache itself with an older version of style-color.php? Does your php file have expires headers, etc etc?

Comment: @Qualcuno Here's an example of the code: http://pastebin.com/9GCW8ZMS

Comment: @JonathanKuhn The link tag is being used. `<link rel='stylesheet' id='some-id'  href='some-path/style-colors.php?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='all' />`.

Comment: add headers `header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");`

Comment: @DaveGoten I've just ruled out browser caching. Nothing indicates header expiration in the `style-colors.php` document.

Comment: @ClarusDignus and the wordpress cache? If you don't know how to clear it manually add a timestamp or version number to the end of the php file in the link (like Kim Alexander mentioned) `<link rel='stylesheet' id='some-id' href='some-path/style-colors.php?ver=1.0&ts=123rand#123' type='text/css' media='all' />`

Comment: @KimAlexander I added your provided headers immeditatly beneath `header( 'Content-type: text/css;' );` though it has taken no effect on the front-end or mark-up.

Comment: do you have link to see and test?

Comment: @KimAlexander Here's a link to the live environment. http://pastebin.com/t8qJyTnX View the source code of the home page and you'll find that that the link to style-colors.php, when followed, doesn't produce the necessary CSS despite doing so locally.

Comment: I can't see this link, firewall blocks me

Comment: @KimAlexander Sorry Kim but are you referring to the pastebin link in my comment or the link found in the pastbin document? ...and if it's the latter, I have no idea what that suggests. I'm able to view it fine on my end and the my Firefox Webutation add-on ranks the site at 90%.

Comment: When I try to load the `style-colors.php` page (first, it doesn't have a get string, but whatever) I get a 404 error. Are you sure the file exists at that location? Also, check that there isn't an htaccess file in one the parent directories that is blocking the script in some way.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I didn't realise it was actually 404ing. I thought the PHP was simply failing to output the CSS. The link path definitely corresponds to a correct and existing file destination. There's a .htaccess file in one of the parent directories that configured automatically by a variety of security plugins. I need to iterate through them to double-check what might be blocking the script. I'll report back soon.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I've belatedly checked my error logs only to find a fatal PHP error inferring `Failed opening required 'wp-load.php'`. It's not being found with the following code (which works locally):  `$url = dirname( __FILE__ ); $strpos = strpos( $url, 'wp-content' ); $base = substr( $url, 0, $strpos ); require_once( $base .'wp-load.php' );`

Answer (score 0):

try this code it be work.

```
    <?php
    $root = dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))));
    if ( file_exists( $root.'/wp-load.php' ) ) {
        require_once( $root.'/wp-load.php' );
    } elseif ( file_exists( $root.'/wp-config.php' ) ) {
        require_once( $root.'/wp-config.php' );
    }
    header("Content-type: text/css");
    // start output buffer
    ob_start();


    $theme_color="#d5266c";
 ?>
    a:hover,
    a:focus{
        color:<?php echo $theme_color;?>;
    }
```

Comment: Good point with setting the "Content-type" header - that fixed my problem! But what the heck's with the ob_start()? Where's the 'echo ob_get_clean()'?